# Accessing Class method from another file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Just for learning , how we can access a class method from another file in ruby. for example

**file1.rb**

```
class Test1

  def abc
    #  ...
  end

  def xyz
    # ...
  end
end
```

for example if i have to access method abc from class Test1 in file1.rb in another file lets say in file2.rb,

**file2.rb**

```
require "file1.rb"

class Test2

# here I would like to call method abc in class Test1
end
```

Comment: Do you have an instance of `Test1`? If you never intend to make instances of the class, then it's a `module`, not a `class`.

Comment: `Test1#abc` is an instance method, so to call such a method in `Test2` you would need an instance of `Test1`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo not necessarily [For instance](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb#L56) and the semantics are a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate the class and then call the method. You can do this in two lines or one.

```
# file1.rb
class Test1
  def abc
    ...
  end
end

# file2.rb
require "file1"

class Test2
  def a_method
    # altogether
    Test1.new.abc

    # to store an object of Test1
    test1 = Test1.new
    test1.abc
  end
end
```